# gatsbyjs query data from graphcms with status condition throw error object undefiend

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Hello i have a gatsbyjs site that i tried to pull data of model 'job' from graphcms. if i pull alljob. the query works fine but if i try to put condition to pull only the job with the status field pubished. it didnt pull any data and throw an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'allJob' of undefined

Here's my gatsby-node.js:

```
const path = require(`path`);
const makeRequest = (graphql, request) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
  resolve(
    graphql(request).then(result => {
      if (result.errors) {
        reject(result.errors)
      }
      return result;
    })
  )
});

exports.createPages = ({ boundActionCreators, graphql }) => {  
  const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;
  const getJobs = makeRequest(graphql, `
    {
      allJob(where: {status: PUBLISHED}) {
        edges{
          node{
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `).then(result => { result.data.allJob.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `/job/${node.id}`,
          component: path.resolve(`src/templates/jobTemplate.js`),
          context: {
            id: node.id,
          }
        })
        console.log(node.id)
      })
    } 
  )
  return getJobs;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gatsby doesn't understand `allJob(where: {status: PUBLISHED})` as it's the wrong syntax.

You would want to use `filter` instead. I can't give you an example as I don't know how the structure is but can advise you to run `gatsby develop` and go to GraphiQL (`http://localhost:8000/___graphql`) and use it's autocomplete feature (`Ctrl + Space`) to get the right filter.

More information: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter